# XSD: constrain attribute value of element to a substring of parent attribute

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xsd

Consider this piece of XML

```
<Parent id="MyParent1">
   <Child id="MyParent1.MyChild1"/>
</Parent>

<Parent id="MyParent2">
   <Child id="MyParent2.MyChild1"/>
   <Child id="MySillyIncorrectPrefix.MyChild2"/>
</Parent>
```

How can I validate (possibly with XSD) Child elements whose id contains the Parent element id as a prefix, so that:

```
<Child id="MyParent2.MyChild1"/> <!-- is valid -->
<Child id="MySillyIncorrectPrefix.MyChild2"/> <!-- is not valid -->
```

I'm not bound to XSD version 1.0, so I could try with XSD 1.1 (and features like assertions), but I would like to know:

- how to express the above constraint with an xs:assertion or more suitable XSD 1.1
  feature.
- if it's possible to build a validator in Java leveraging on
  that xsd? "Xerces-J" is a feasible solution ?

In my limited knowledge of XSD 1.1 I came up with this attempt:

```
<xs:element name="Child"> 
  <xs:complexType>
     <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:String" />
     <xs:assert test="starts-with(@type,../@type)"/>
</xs:complexType> 
</xs:element>
```

Is this correct? Is there a tool where I could test it?
Being more general: is there a tool to assist the build&test of such XSD 1.1 featured schemas? (afaik Eclipse supports only XSD 1.0)

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is not feasible in XSD 1.0.

In XSD 1.1 you can use assertions on the type of the parent to require each child's id attribute to begin with the value of the parent's id attribute.

Comment: Do you have suggestions on how to express this constraint with an "xs:assertion"?

Comment: Yes, but Stack Overflow is for helping people solve problems they are running into difficulties solving on their own, not for doing contract work for free. What have you tried?

Comment: It is not my intention to free-load, but only to get a piece of advice.
Your answer was useful because pointed me to XSD 1.1, that now I'm studying.
In the learning process I'm asking help for an example. I think that SO is the right place for that.

From my part I tried to build a clear "use case" so that providing an example could be easy for an expert and the shared knowledge could be generic and useful for many. In any case I'll make a try, see below

Answer (score 0):

This schema should validate the example (use an xsd 1.1 assertion)

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/stackoverflow" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/stackoverflow" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <complexType name="ParentType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="Child" type="tns:ChildType"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            </element>
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="id" type="string"></attribute> 
    </complexType>

    <element name="Parent" type="tns:ParentType"></element>

    <complexType name="ChildType">
        <attribute name="id" type="string"></attribute>
        <assert test="starts-with(@id,../@id)"/>
    </complexType>

</schema>
```